# Including Leaflet.js in a Django template

Tags: django, leaflet

I am writing a Django app that displays properties of certain objects that have latitute and longitude associated with them.  When someone clicks on an object name, I'd like to be able to show them the map of where the objects is.  I tried including leaflet.js's map directly into my object detailed view's template like this:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ=="  crossorigin=""/>

{% block content %}
<div id="mapid" style="width: 10px; height: 10px;"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512/Nsx9X4HebavoBvEBuyp3I7od5tA0UzAxs+j83KgC8PU0kgB4XiK4Lfe4y4cgBtaRJQEIFCW+oC506aPT2L1zw==" crossorigin=""></script>

<script>
  var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

  L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
   attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
  maxZoom: 18,
  id: 'mapbox.streets',
  accessToken: '<my-token-here>'
}).addTo(mymap);

 </script>

{% endblock %}
```

But this gives me the weirdest looking map - it's split into several pieces and I seem to be able to move it freely around the web page into random spots (see below and scroll all the way down, you'll see the break in the middle).   Can anyone tell why?

[image]

Comment: but if you try to render this in a html?